# empty space above content in google chrome and IE

Tags: php, css, drupal

We have developed a website with drupal. Everything is working fine except one page. There was a empty space above the content in chrome and IE. In Firefox it is working fine. Below is the url

http://www.infronics.com/news-room/news-events

Please help me in resolving the issue

Comment: It's not 1998. Please stop using tables for layout purposes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It has to do with your `.sidebar1` div. It is being hid behind your content but still taking up space. My guess is because you have `display:table` or `display:table-row` on almost all of the parent divs.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like there's a div called .sidebar1 that's taking up all that space.

http://cl.ly/image/30252D011p20